# Passing JQuery value to html and then tally the totals with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass on JQuery values to hidden textboxes (to send as a form later) as well as divs t

hat displays on the front end. I also want to tally these items as the value is passed to them. I have Frankensteined this bit of code which passes on the value to the the input boxes and the divs and it also tallies them onclick. I am just struggling to get the sum to display in #total_div. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#my_div').click(function() {
$('#my_value_1').val("100");
$('#my_value_1_div').html( "100" );
$('#my_div').click(addNumbers('total'));
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#my_div_2').click(function() {
$('#my_value_2').val("200");
$('#my_value_2_div').html( "200" );
$('#my_div_2').click(addNumbers('total'));
});
});

function addNumbers()
{
var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_1").value);
var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_2").value);
var ansD = document.getElementById("total");
ansD.value = val1 + val2;
}
</script>

 <h2>My pretty front end</h2>

<div id="my_div">ADD THIS VALUE 1</div>

<div id="my_div_2">ADD THIS VALUE 2</div>

VALUE 1: <div id="my_value_1_div">VALUE 1 GOES HERE</div>

VALUE 2: <div id="my_value_2_div">VALUE 2 GOES HERE</div>

TOTAL: <div id="total_div">SUM MUST GO HERE</div>

<h2>My hidden Form</h2>

Value 1: <input type="text" id="my_value_1" name="my_value_1" value="0"/>
Value 2: <input type="text" id="my_value_2" name="my_value_2" value="0"/>
<input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()"/>
Total: <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value=""/>
```

EDIT

Ok so thanks to the advice I got the above working but now I need to clear the amounts. This is what I have done, it is almost there I think but I'm getting the incorrect sum.

```
$('#clear').click(function() {
$('#my_value_1').val('0');
$('#my_value_1_div').html( "0" );
$('#clear').click(minusNumbers('total'));
 });    

function minusNumbers()
{
var minval1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_1").value);
var minval2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value);
var minansD = document.getElementById("total");
minansD.value = minval2 - minval1;
$('#total_div').text(minansD.value);
}
```

Comment: Use `minval2.value - minval1.value`

Comment: Ask your further doubts as a New Question

Comment: Thanks @Sam1604, but now I get NaN value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `#total_div` text in `addNumber` function as,

```
function addNumbers()
{
var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_1").value);
var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_2").value);
var ansD = document.getElementById("total");
ansD.value = val1 + val2;
$('#total_div').text(ansD.value);
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/qh4nfc2s/)

Comment: You beauties! So simple. It works like a charm! Thank you. I've run into another snag. Im trying to clear that value (working) and minus it from the total.  I think I am on the right track but it spits out the incorrect sum. I will edit the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
function addNumbers()
{
var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_1").value);
var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_2").value);
var ansD = document.getElementById("total");
ansD.value = val1 + val2;
}
```

with:

```
function addNumbers()
{
var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_1").value);
var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_2").value);
var ansD = document.getElementById("total");
ansD = val1 + val2;
$('#total').val(ansD);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

click(addNumbers('total')); first calls addNumbers with an unused parameter 'total' then gets the return value of addNumbers (null or undefined) and sets that as the click() handler for the next click.

I think you probably meant

```
$('#my_div').click(addNumbers);
```

that means, "run the addNumbers function, defined below, next time I click my_div".

or just

```
addNumbers();
```

that means, "run the addNumbers function now" (at the first click)

Note though that when you click and call addNumbers, one of the numbers may not yet be copied, so you would be adding 100+"" or ""+200 so you really have to think about what you want to do.