# Clearing and subtracting JQuery values onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to clear a value from an input box (#my_value_1) and then subtract that amount from the totals (#total and #total_div).

This is what I have done so far... I have passed JQuery values to hidden textboxes and divs successfully as well as tallied these items as the value is passed to them. I have managed to 'clear' #my_value and #my_value_2 from the input box and div but now I am struggling to subtract those values from #total and #total_div. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_div').click(function() {
        $('#my_value_1').val("100");
        $('#my_value_1_div').html("100");
        $('#my_div').click(addNumbers('total'));
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_div_2').click(function() {
        $('#my_value_2').val("200");
        $('#my_value_2_div').html("200");
        $('#my_div_2').click(addNumbers('total'));
    });
});

function addNumbers() {
    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_1").value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_2").value);
    var ansD = document.getElementById("total");
    ansD.value = val1 + val2;
    $('#total_div').text(ansD.value);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clear').click(function() {
        $('#my_value_1').val('0');
        $('#my_value_1_div').html("0");
        $('#clear').click(minusNumbers());
    });
});

function minusNumbers() {
    var minval1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_1").value);
    var minval2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value);
    var minansD = document.getElementById("total");
    minansD.value = minval2 - minval1;
    $('#total_div').text(minansD.value);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clear2').click(function() {
        $('#my_value_2').val('0');
        $('#my_value_2_div').html("0");
        $('#clear').click(minusNumbers());
    });
});

function minusNumbers() {
    var minval1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_2").value);
    var minval2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value);
    var minansD = document.getElementById("total");
    minansD.value = minval2 - minval1;
    $('#total_div').text(minansD.value);
}
</script>

<h2>My pretty front end</h2>

<div id="my_div">ADD THIS VALUE 1</div>

<div id="my_div_2">ADD THIS VALUE 2</div>

VALUE 1:
<div id="my_value_1_div">0</div>

VALUE 2:
<div id="my_value_2_div">0</div>

TOTAL:
<div id="total_div">0</div>

<div id="clear">CLEAR VALUE 1</div>

<div id="clear2">CLEAR VALUE 2</div>

<h2>My hidden Form</h2>

Value 1:
<input type="text" id="my_value_1" name="my_value_1" value="0" />Value 2:
<input type="text" id="my_value_2" name="my_value_2" value="0" />
<input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()" />Total:
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" />
```

Comment: What is your output? Also, personal request, could you put indentation in to your code? I'm finding it hard to follow :)

Comment: you don't need to use `document.ready` multiple times, it should be once throughout the document and include all event handlers in it.

Comment: The above comments apply to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26012306/2333214) as well... P.s: i don't see any effort from your end... this is a follow up question posted within an hour... feels like you are crowd sourcing your work.

Comment: Thank you Gorb I will remember that in future, but I am not really following your question. Thank you for the tip Bhushan Kawadasar. TJ, with all due respect I have been working on this code for almost 2 days, I am a complete JS novice so your effort levels and mine are most likely worlds apart. I was told to post a new question as opposed to just editing my previous one, that is why this is here.

Comment: I've edited the Question, but I really do not see why it was marked as unclear in the first place. It was answered correctly by @Quince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry just realized the error i pointed out below was because i placed my js in the fiddle to run onLoad so of course was out of scope you can ignore this first bit but i think the answer still applies to your question, please correct me if im wrong.

<s>SO the error it was showing in the console was that addNumbers was undefined. This is because it was out of scope. One solution for this is to bind a click event on to the button like you have done with your divs. If this was part of a form you can also pass the event to the callback function and call `event.preventDefault()` to stop if from trying to submit the form.</s>

So here is a slightly reworked example, I also noticed there was no real need for the minus numbers as you only ever really need to add the numbers up to get the total (unless i was misunderstanding the purpose in which case it can be added back in)

```js
$('#my_div').click(function() {
  $('#my_value_1').val("100");
  $('#my_value_1_div').html("100");
  addNumbers();
});

$('#my_div_2').click(function() {
  $('#my_value_2').val("200");
  $('#my_value_2_div').html("200");
  addNumbers();
});
$('#clear').click(function() {
  $('#my_value_1').val('0');
  $('#my_value_1_div').html("0");
  addNumbers();
});

$('#clear2').click(function() {
  $('#my_value_2').val('0');
  $('#my_value_2_div').html("0");
  addNumbers();
});


$('#totalNumbers').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  addNumbers();
});


function addNumbers() {
  var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_1").value);
  var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_value_2").value);
  var ansD = document.getElementById("total");
  ansD.value = val1 + val2;
  $('#total_div').text(ansD.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>My pretty front end</h2>

<div id="my_div">ADD THIS VALUE 1</div>
<div id="my_div_2">ADD THIS VALUE 2</div>VALUE 1:
<div id="my_value_1_div">0</div>VALUE 2:
<div id="my_value_2_div">0</div>TOTAL:
<div id="total_div">0</div>
<div id="clear">CLEAR VALUE 1</div>
<div id="clear2">CLEAR VALUE 2</div>

<h2>My hidden Form</h2>
Value 1:
<input type="text" id="my_value_1" name="my_value_1" value="0" />Value 2:
<input type="text" id="my_value_2" name="my_value_2" value="0" />
<input type="button" id="totalNumbers" name="Sumbit" value="Click here" />Total:
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Quince, this looks perfect. It is way simpler than what I was trying, JS noob sorry. But I'm learning :)